# How to get update fields in another model using ORM methods in open erp

Tags: python, xml, odoo

I am new to openERP so i started working on basic module creation.

i've created HOTEL management module using 4 different model names. 1.room.info [Rooms information],2.room.book [book a room, many2one relation with room.info],3.room.vacant [vacant rooms],4.room.engaged [engaged rooms]

what i want is whenever i create room info it should come to room.vacant model (vacant rooms) and also whenever the customer books a room it should come to room.engaged model and also vacant rooms should get updated. I am not getting ORM methods properly. Please help me out.Thanks in advance

[Here is the image of my module](https://i.stack.imgur.com/nUWcs.png)

CODE:

```
from openerp.osv import fields, osv
from openerp import api
from datetime import datetime, timedelta
import datetime

class Hotel(osv.osv):
_name = 'hotel.book'

_columns ={

    'c_name' : fields.char('Customer name',required=True),
    'room_num' : fields.many2one('room.info','Room number', required=True),
    'charges' : fields.float('Price'),
    'mobile' : fields.char('Mobile Number', size=64, required=True),
    'charges' : fields.float('Price'),
    'check_in':fields.date('Check In'),
    'check_out':fields.date('Check Out'),
    'days': fields.float('Number of Days'),
    'total' : fields.float('Amount'),


        }
Hotel()

 class RoomInfo(osv.osv):
     _name='room.info'
     _rec_name='room_num'

     _columns = {

        'room_num':fields.integer('Room Number'),
        'status':fields.selection([('reserved', 'Reserved'),('vacant', 'Vacant')],'Status'),

               }

   RoomInfo()

   class VacantRooms(osv.osv):
       _name='room.vacant'
       _columns = {

           'room_num' : fields.many2one('room.info','Room number'),

            }

   VacantRooms()

   class EngagedRooms(osv.osv):
       _name='room.engage'
       _columns = {

          'room_num' : fields.many2one('room.info','Room number'),
          'status':fields.selection([('reserved', 'Reserved'),('vacant', 'Vacant')],'Status'),


}
    EngagedRooms()
```

Comment: Check the [official doc](https://www.odoo.com/documentation/8.0/howtos/backend.html) for build the odoo module. It might be help to you..  :)

Comment: Thanks but... i get struck at ORM methods ... can you plz send examples about its functionality.. How to get codes?

Comment: Yup... there is it... It's all in that doc.  Link to [ORM API](https://www.odoo.com/documentation/8.0/reference/orm.html)

Answer (score 0):

You can try this code:

```python
from openerp import fields, models


class Hotel(models.Model):
    _name = 'hotel.book'

    c_name = fields.Char('Customer name', required=True)
    room_num = fields.Many2one('room.info', 'Room number', required=True)
    charges = fields.Float('Price')
    mobile = fields.Char('Mobile Number', required=True)
    charges = fields.Float('Price')
    check_in = fields.Date('Check In')
    check_out = fields.Date('Check Out')
    days = fields.Float('Number of Days')
    total = fields.Float('Amount')


class RoomInfo(models.Model):
    _name = 'room.info'

    room_num = fields.Integer('Room Number')
    status = fields.Selection([('reserved', 'Reserved'), ('vacant', 'Vacant')], string='Status')


class VacantRooms(models.Model):
    _name = 'room.vacant'

    room_num = fields.Many2one('room.info', 'Room number')


class EngagedRooms(models.Model):
    _name = 'room.engage'

    room_num = fields.Many2one('room.info', 'Room number')
    status = fields.Selection([('reserved', 'Reserved'), ('vacant', 'Vacant')], 'Status')
```